# How to debug Json between Local IIS Website and Local

Tags: rest, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, fiddler, wcf-web-api

I'm really struggling to know what the problem is here...

I have 2 websites configured in IIS...

```
**PH.Website**   (STANDARD MVC PROJECT)

**PH.Api**       (MVC WEB API PRIOJECT)
```

When you hit the PH.Website it uses a WebClient class in one of the controllers to download data from the PH.Api. However fiddler only sees traffic going to the PH.Website not the PH.Api.

After reading around on the internet I apparently have to do some configuration of the Syste.Net in the Web Api Project. So I added...

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy
              usesystemdefault="False"
              bypassonlocal="True"
              proxyaddress="http://PH.Api"
              />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

But still no luck. I know the request is happening I just cant see it.

Whats even more confusing is when I configure Fiddler to use Port 80 its says it cannot listen on that port. But hang on if it cant listen on 80 then how the hell can it see traffic on the Http port:80 anyway?

P.s. I really need to be able to run multiple sites locally so. I hate running sites under Localhost or 127.0.0.1 seems so silly when you can create seperate sites for everything in IIS and know exactly where everything maps....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's back up.

Fiddler's a proxy server; it sees all of the traffic that is sent to it. Generally speaking (unless you're using it as a Reverse Proxy) you never want to configure *Fiddler* to run on port 80; instead leave it up at port 8888 where it runs by default. You instead configure your *client* to proxy its traffic *through* Fiddler.

Now, what "reading around on the Internet" did you do that caused you to modify your machine.config or web.config file (you didn't mention which you edited)?

If your goal is to watch traffic with Fiddler, you need to [point the ASP.NET proxy settings at Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/blog/blog/2013/01/08/capturing-traffic-from-.net-services-with-fiddler), not at whatever "PH.api" is (e.g. use "127.0.0.1:8888" and set bypassOnLocal to false). The further complexity arises in that System.NET bypasses the proxy for any request to "localhost" or "127.0.0.1", so if you're using those addresses for your target, you should change them to "localhost.fiddler" temporarily while debugging.

Comment: YESSSS thankyou very much. I Set up my MVC project to point to fiddler on 127.0.0.1:8888 and it works. Here's my other quick q though, how does fiddler know how to forward the traffic to though? This concept of proxy confuses me in terms of how it works ( I know what the word proxy means). How how my packets actually end up at the PH.api?

To answer your question I changed the machine, after your advice I changed the web.config. I think changing the web.config is more clear for learning purposes....

Comment: A proxy server is informed of the target of a request by way of the HTTP request line (first line of the headers) and the HOST header.